# Orbeon - Access to created and last_modified within form

Tags: orbeon

How do I get access (i.e. set a text box) to the created and last_modified values?

Answer (score 1):

The created and last modified date is returned by the [search operation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-Search-API) of the persistence REST API, so this information can be displayed in the summary page. However, it is not available as part of the form data, and at this point you can't access it from within a form, when the form is displayed.